# How can the effect size of a PERMANOVA be calculated?

Tags: r, vegan

I use the "vegan" package to perform a PERMANOVA (`adonis2()`), and I also want to calculate the effect size (ω²). For this, I tried to use `omega_squared()` from the "effectsize" package, but I failed. I think it does not understand the output table, specifically the part with the mean squares. Is it possible to fix this or do I have to calculate manually?

```r
library(vegan)
#> Lade nötiges Paket: permute
#> Lade nötiges Paket: lattice
#> This is vegan 2.6-4
library(effectsize)

data(dune)
data(dune.env)

ado <- adonis2(dune ~ Management, data = dune.env, permutations = 100)

ado
#> Permutation test for adonis under reduced model
#> Terms added sequentially (first to last)
#> Permutation: free
#> Number of permutations: 100
#> 
#> adonis2(formula = dune ~ Management, data = dune.env, permutations = 100)
#>            Df SumOfSqs      R2      F   Pr(>F)   
#> Management  3   1.4686 0.34161 2.7672 0.009901 **
#> Residual   16   2.8304 0.65839                   
#> Total      19   4.2990 1.00000                   
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

w2 <- omega_squared(ado)
#> Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Mean_Square", value = numeric(0)): Ersetzung hat 0 Zeilen, Daten haben 3
interpret_omega_squared(w2)
#> Error in interpret(es, rules): Objekt 'w2' nicht gefunden
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

**EDIT**

I tried to do it manually:

```r
library(vegan, quietly = T, warn.conflicts = F)
#> This is vegan 2.6-4
library(effectsize)
library(dplyr, quietly = T, warn.conflicts = F)
library(tibble)
library(purrr)

data(dune)
data(dune.env)

ado <- adonis2(dune ~ Management, data = dune.env, permutations = 100)

w2 <- omega_squared(ado) # Does not work
#> Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Mean_Square", value = numeric(0)): Ersetzung hat 0 Zeilen, Daten haben 3
interpret_omega_squared(w2) # Does not work
#> Error in interpret(es, rules): Objekt 'w2' nicht gefunden

ado_tidy <- tibble( # manually create Adonis test result table
  parameter = c("Management", "Residual", "Total"),
  df = ado %>% pull("Df"), # Degree of freedom
  ss = ado %>% pull("SumOfSqs"), # sum of squares
  meansqs = ss / df, # mean squares
  p_r2 = ado %>% pull("R2"), # partial R²
  f = ado %>% pull("F"), # F value
  p = ado %>% pull("Pr(>F)") # p value
  )

ado_tidy
#> # A tibble: 3 x 7
#>   parameter     df    ss meansqs  p_r2     f        p
#>   <chr>      <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 Management     3  1.47   0.490 0.342  2.77  0.00990
#> 2 Residual      16  2.83   0.177 0.658 NA    NA      
#> 3 Total         19  4.30   0.226 1     NA    NA

# Formula:
# W2 = (DFm * (F - 1)) / ((DFm * (F - 1)) + (DFm + 1)) 

W2 <- abs(
  (ado_tidy %>% pull(df) %>% chuck(3) * (ado_tidy %>% pull(f) %>% chuck(1) - 1)) /
    ((ado_tidy %>% pull(df) %>% chuck(3) * (ado_tidy %>% pull(f) %>% chuck(1) - 1) +
      ado_tidy %>% pull(df) %>% chuck(3) + 1)
     )
  )

W2
#> [1] 0.6267099
interpret_omega_squared(W2, rules = "field2013")
#> [1] "large"
#> (Rules: field2013)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Hopefully, the equation is correct...

Comment: I think you first need to develop the theory of calculating effect size in `adonis2`.

Comment: I found that there is already an approach to calculate ω² for an ```adonis()``` test, but that does not work with ```adonis2()```. I found ```MicEco::adonis_OmegaSq()```, so I thought ω² is the correct effect size to use.

Comment: The latest version of MicEco in github has an upgraded version of adonis_OmegaSq that also works with vegan::adonis2 (it also works with the deprecated adonis).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the `MicEco::adonis_OmegaSq` function edited so that it works both with the current `vegan::adonis2` and deprecated `vegan::adonis`:

```
#' Calculate (partial) Omega-squared (effect-size calculation) for PERMANOVA and add it to the input object
#'
#' @param adonisOutput An adonis object
#' @param partial Should partial omega-squared be calculated (sample size adjusted). Default TRUE
#' @return Original adonis object with the (partial) Omega-squared values added
#' @import vegan
#' @export
adonis_OmegaSq <- function(adonisOutput, partial = TRUE){
    if(!(is(adonisOutput, "adonis") || is(adonisOutput, "anova.cca")))
        stop("Input should be an adonis object")
    if (is(adonisOutput, "anova.cca")) {
        aov_tab <- adonisOutput
        aov_tab$MeanSqs <- aov_tab$SumOfSqs / aov_tab$Df
        aov_tab$MeanSqs[length(aov_tab$Df)] <- NA
    } else {
        aov_tab <- adonisOutput$aov.tab
    }
    heading <- attr(aov_tab, "heading")
    MS_res <- aov_tab[pmatch("Residual", rownames(aov_tab)), "MeanSqs"]
    SS_tot <- aov_tab[rownames(aov_tab) == "Total", "SumsOfSqs"]
    N <- aov_tab[rownames(aov_tab) == "Total", "Df"] + 1
    if(partial){
        omega <- apply(aov_tab, 1, function(x) (x["Df"]*(x["MeanSqs"]-MS_res))/(x["Df"]*x["MeanSqs"]+(N-x["Df"])*MS_res))
        aov_tab$parOmegaSq <- c(omega[1:(length(omega)-2)], NA, NA)
    } else {
        omega <- apply(aov_tab, 1, function(x) (x["SumsOfSqs"]-x["Df"]*MS_res)/(SS_tot+MS_res))
        aov_tab$OmegaSq <- c(omega[1:(length(omega)-2)], NA, NA)
    }
    if (is(adonisOutput, "adonis"))
        cn_order <- c("Df", "SumsOfSqs", "MeanSqs", "F.Model", "R2",
                      if (partial) "parOmegaSq" else "OmegaSq", "Pr(>F)")
    else
        cn_order <- c("Df", "SumOfSqs", "F", if (partial) "parOmegaSq" else "OmegaSq",
                      "Pr(>F)")
    aov_tab <- aov_tab[, cn_order]
    attr(aov_tab, "names") <- cn_order
    attr(aov_tab, "heading") <- heading
    if (is(adonisOutput, "adonis"))
        adonisOutput$aov.tab <- aov_tab
    else
        adonisOutput <- aov_tab
    return(adonisOutput)
}
```

`source()` this function and it should work. In my test it gave the same results for both `adonis2` and `adonis`.

Comment: It's working with my data. Many thanks for this great improvement!

Comment: this answer is fantastic, @Jari. This topic needs amplified generally, as measuring effect sizes and power calculations for PERMANOVA strike me as something that many folks would like to do it if were more readily available. Every time I have to use micropower, I cringe a little